# Simplification of running times of algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

Noob question but can someone explain the method used to simplify the equation on the first line to the equation on the second line?  I'm rusty, is it polynomial factoring?

[Sum of instruction times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85nNJ.png)

TIA

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions rather than posting images. Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs. Use ^ for exponents and _ for subscripts. `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Answer (score 1):

When you multiply out the first line, you get

$$c_1n+c_2n-c_2+c_4n-c_4+c_5n-c_5+c_8n-c_8\,.$$

You can then collect the multiples of $n$ and factor out the $n$ to get

$$c_1n+c_2n+c_4n+c_5n+c_8n=\color{red}{(c_1+c_2+c_4+c_5+c_8)n}\,.$$

Finally, you can combine the constants and factor out the minus sign to get

$$-c_2-c_4-c_5-c_8=\color{red}{-(c_2+c_4+c_5+c_8)},.$$

Now just add the two (red) final forms to get

$$(c_1+c_2+c_4+c_5+c_8)n-(c_2+c_4+c_5+c_8)\,.$$